# How to get count number of SelectedNode with XPath in C#?

Tags: c#, xpath, count, html-agility-pack

I am using HTMLAgilityPack in my application, and i want to get the item(node) count of SelectedNodes as the code below:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
var tagListe = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
var divListe = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='o']");
```

At the first, getting a href was successfully running, but second one i prefer to get special class named "o" there was en error.

I want to use .Count but got an error. Also foreach loop running for the firs selectedNodes which i request a tags href attribute. And didn't run for class filtering.

Hot to get count of `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='o']")`

Thank you,
Caglar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specific way in `HTMLAgilityPack` but in plain XPath you can do this:

`count(//div[@class='o'])`

You properly can't use this XPath in `.SelectNodes` but there should be a method like `Evaluate`, `SelectSingle` or `SelectAtom`.